# Conditionally format with a different colour for each unique set of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, excel-2013

I often deal with multi-week bookings of venues in a spreadsheet.  Below is an example:

```
Row  Date        Day       Time    Venue
1    20/02/2014  Thursday  9:00am  Meeting Room 3
2     6/03/2014  Thursday  9:00am  Meeting Room 3
3    20/03/2014  Thursday  2:00pm  Meeting Room 3
4     3/04/2014  Thursday  9:00am  Meeting Room 3
5    18/04/2014  Friday    9:00am  Meeting Room 3
6     1/05/2014  Thursday  9:00am  Conference Room
7    15/05/2014  Thursday  2:00pm  Meeting Room 3
```

Is it possible to use Conditional Formatting so that each unique set of Day, Time and Venue has a different background colour?

In the above example, rows 1, 2 and 4 would be red, 3 and 7 would be orange, and rows 5 and 6 would be yellow and green respectively.

Comment: i guess you have to use a helper column? and also you need to define how many combination there is.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, say with three rules of this kind:

```
=AND($B2="Friday",$C2="9:00am",$D2="Meeting Room 3")
```

That's the example for yellow (I did not bother with green as the 'default' does not require CF).

However, `Meeting Room 3` implies there may be two others and even if only weekdays are relevant and only two sessions are possible (effectively am or pm) that is still a lot of possible combinations - each a separate colour therefore each a separate rule, if of the kind above. And in Excel a lot of colours can be counterproductive - instead of drawing attention to specific ranges they can just be confusing.

So I'd suggest trying a different approach, such as (possibly) splitting Time into a column for am and another for pm, or (possibly) sorting by Date but within Venue.